# Have we seen any of the babies Michael and Harry saved again?

Tags: the-dresden-files

In Dresden Files book 3, *Grave Peril*, Harry and Michael Carpenter confront the ghost of Agatha Hagglethorn in the maternity ward of a hospital.

Agatha is in the process of murdering the newborns by suffocation.  There is one specifically that she focuses on, shoving the stump of her arm into it's mouth to smother it.

The good guys win the day and save all the kids, and I distinctly recall Harry making note of the baby's name (though I don't have my copy at hand, so I can't look it up).

It seems strange to me that we would get a specific name for a child that isn't seen again.  Similarly, it seems like such dramatic supernatural contact as a newborn could have lasting effects on the child.

Obviously, it will be years before the infant is old enough to impact Harry's stories again.

By book 14, Cold Days, years have passed.  How many years have passed between book 3 and 14?  Have we seen this child again?  What was her name?

Comment: not an answer but a good reference: http://www.jimbutcheronline.com/bb/index.php?topic=1592.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the second part of your question is that about 11 years have passed between *Grave Peril* and *Cold Days*, so the infants that were saved in that novel would be about 11 to 12 years old.

The name of the infant Harry saves directly is Alison Ann Summers. As far as I know we have never seen nor even heard from that girl again.

(Unrelated side note: the last name "Summers", of course, leads to all kinds of Buffy/Harry fan fiction.)

Comment: Hmm...11 or 12, right on the verge of when magical talents will start appearing.  I guess I'll be patient and wait for a few more books.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

While the rescued infants may not have reappeared (yet) in later novels, they do indirectly contribute to a minor plot point in *Dead Beat*: When Harry needs information from an EMT at Cook County Hospital, Jason Lamar agrees to help specifically because of Harry & Michael's heroics in the nursery ward.

Comment: Oh yes!  I loved that callback.